# How to run WebBrowser in another process, but in the original application

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

My application is something like Chrome or Firefox and allow to create and destroy tabs with WebBrowser object. It is very rough description, but close to understand what app is doing.

The problem is that the WebBrowser object is based on Internet Explorer (IE) and IE has a memory leak in deep of .Net unmanaged memory if closed site have some JS code or images (which is 99.99% of sites).

I tried every solution from web and finally I have got a confirmation from MS that this issue based on IE architecture and it can't be fixed by any trick from the code perspective (object cleaning or calling GC).
So, I started thinking in different way to solve the problem.

The problem is that the leak happened in unmanaged memory of .Net WebBrowser object and .Net does not clear it properly when WebBrowser object destroyed. But it happens in my application process ID.

So, I am looking for some option to **separate memory for my application and for WebBrowser object** (create it in a separate process). I know that Chrome is working in similar way (one process per one tab) which makes this idea realistic at least. But I can't find any info how can I do it to display WebBrowser in my app as it was before.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You can change the parent of a window with the native call `SetWindowParent`

Comment: Use something better than IE? E.g. cefsharp for Chrome.

Comment: So, these web browser control instances, they are expected to run in a separate child process, but the same overarching window visually?